# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE user privilege settings

Tags: security, mysql, permissions

I understand that users must have `FILE` privilege on `*.*` in order to use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command without using `LOCAL`—which sends the file data through the client—but when `GRANT`ing `FILE` privilege to a MySQL user, how can you restrict the directories from which a user can load data from (similar to `secure_file_priv`, but user-specific)?

What is best-practice in this regard? To simply force users to use the `LOCAL` keyword and sacrifice a little performance for security, or grant `FILE` privilege to database users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start off by saying that `FILE` is by far the most dangerous privileges you can give to a application.  `FILE` is much more dangerous than `GRANT`  because in sql injection for mysql you cannot stack quires,  thus you cannot turn a `SELECT`  into a `GRANT` statement and there for this privilege is completely useless for sql injection.  By contrast `FILE` privileges are **commonly** used by exploits to upload a backdoor.

For instance here is an example of sql injection using `into outfile`
`select name from user where id=1 union select "<?php eval($_GET[e])?>" into outfile "/var/www/backdoor.php"`

If your try this query on an Ubuntu system it will fail.  This is because AppArmor is denying MySQL write access to /var/www/.  You could modify AppArmor's rules to deny read/write access to any folder you choose.   AppArmor's configuration is pretty straight forward and you can modify it here: `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`.

If you are on a distro that doesn't support AppArmor you could still use the built-in Linux file permissions,  keep in mind that these file io functions are going to be run by the user account that is executing MySQL. `chown user -R /some/dir && chmod 700 -R /some/dir`.

Answer (score 2):

First we need to make sure that the user has the necessary permissions:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mysql_user'@'hostname';
```

**1. If you have Ubuntu, you can simply disable AppAprmor.**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor kill
sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
```

**2. But this is not the best way to solve the problem.**
It is best to set up a AppArmor profile for mysql.

You just need to add a line to AppAprmor profile to enable 
reading-writing in the required  directory.
For example:

```
/var/www/mysite/** rw,
```

And then restart AppArmor by this cmd:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
/etc/init.d/apparmor start
```

**3. Third way to solve this issue - disabling MySQL AppArmor profile:**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

This works for me on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Disabling AppArmor isn't a good idea, it's better to instruct users to go with 2.